# How do I add elements to a list from another list?

Tags: python, mean, k-means, nested-lists

The code finds the smallest item in each list, I want to add that data point to a list based off of the
list it was from. I also want to be able to find the mean of each cluster.

```
import numpy as np

centroids = np.array([[3,44],[5,15],[99,12]])
dataPoints = np.array([[2,4],[17,4],[45,2],[45,7],[16,32],[32,14],[20,56],[68,33]])

def size(vector):
    return np.sqrt(sum(x**2 for x in vector))

def distance(vector1, vector2):
    return size(vector1 - vector2)

def distances(array1, array2):
    lists = [[distance(vector1, vector2) for vector2 in array2] for vector1 in array1]
    x = 1
    for i in lists:
        print ('Distance from Centroid {}:{}\n'.format(x,i))
        x=x+1

    print map(min, zip(*lists))

distances(centroids,dataPoints)
```

My Output:

```
Distance from Centroid 1:[40.01249804748511, 42.379240200834182, 59.396969619669989, 55.97320787662612, 17.691806012954132, 41.725292090050132, 20.808652046684813, 65.924198895398035]

Distance from Centroid 2:[11.401754250991379, 16.278820596099706, 42.059481689626182, 40.792156108742276, 20.248456731316587, 27.018512172212592, 43.657759905886145, 65.520989003524662]

Distance from Centroid 3:[97.329337817535773, 82.389319696183918, 54.918120870983927, 54.230987451824994, 85.37564055396598, 67.029844099475568, 90.426765949026404, 37.443290453698111]

[11.401754250991379, 16.278820596099706, 42.059481689626182, 40.792156108742276, 17.691806012954132, 27.018512172212592, 20.808652046684813, 37.443290453698111]
```

Additional Desired Output:

```
Cluster 1: [[16,32],[20,56]]
Cluster 2: [[2,4],[17,4],[45,2],[45,7],[32,14]]
Cluster 3: [[68,33]]

List of means :[[18,44],[28.2,6.2],[68,33]]
```

For this example, the amount of centroids/clusters are defined.
What if they are dynamic and the cluster lists need to be created on the fly?

Comment: These are *arrays*. Not *lists*. Or at least, you seem to be mixing the two. Why not just stick with lists?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga If I check the type(lists) it returns the value 'list'. I am aware that I start out with numpy arrays. In your concept to the solution of the problem, does using either have an advantage over the other?

Comment: @Yes, `lists` will be a list because it is assigne the result of a *list-comprehension*. I'm not sure what you are trying to do, though.

Comment: What is a "cluster" here? Are you justr trying to implement k-means? Why don't you use a library like `sklearn`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I added what the current output is if your run the program. What I want to do is take each of the smallest distances found from each data point to each centroid (program already does this). Find out which 'Distance from Centroid' list the smallest distance was from (1-3) in this example. Find what the corresponding data point was (from the nparray, which you could look at as a list if it makes you happy), and assign it to a new list called 'Cluster X' where 'x' is the number of the cluster that is the same as the 'Distance from' list.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it is for a homework assignment. Yes it is a k-means algorithm that is completely from scratch without using the sklearn library.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga In the program above, there are 3 elements in the list 'lists'. Those elements are lists themselves. How do I tell from the zip list of smallest distances which distance the distance was from?

Comment: You have to keep track somehow. I'll post an example as an answer.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga What if instead of getting the smallest distance, I got the index of the smallest index? That would be the same as what I am wanting to do i think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose, you are in the general situation where you want to tell "from which list that is being zipped did the element come from", well, you have to keep track of that:

```
>>> import random
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> ls = [[random.randint(80,200) for _ in range(8)] for _ in range(3)]
>>> pprint(ls)
[[114, 196, 185, 192, 129, 183, 150, 189],
 [173, 173, 116, 135, 109, 87, 80, 88],
 [159, 173, 139, 189, 100, 107, 102, 188]]
>>> [min(zip(l,range(len(l)))) for l in zip(*ls)]
[(114, 0), (173, 1), (116, 1), (135, 1), (100, 2), (87, 1), (80, 1), (88, 1)]
```

Applied to your situation:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>>
>>> centroids = np.array([[3,44],[5,15],[99,12]])
>>> dataPoints = np.array([[2,4],[17,4],[45,2],[45,7],[16,32],[32,14],[20,56],[68,33]])
>>>
>>> def size(vector):
...     return np.sqrt(sum(x**2 for x in vector))
...
>>> def distance(vector1, vector2):
...     return size(vector1 - vector2)
...
>>> lists = [[distance(vector1, vector2) for vector2 in dataPoints] for vector1 in centroids]
>>> pprint(lists)
[[40.01249804748511,
  42.379240200834182,
  59.396969619669989,
  55.97320787662612,
  17.691806012954132,
  41.725292090050132,
  20.808652046684813,
  65.924198895398035],
 [11.401754250991379,
  16.278820596099706,
  42.059481689626182,
  40.792156108742276,
  20.248456731316587,
  27.018512172212592,
  43.657759905886145,
  65.520989003524662],
 [97.329337817535773,
  82.389319696183918,
  54.918120870983927,
  54.230987451824994,
  85.37564055396598,
  67.029844099475568,
  90.426765949026404,
  37.443290453698111]]
>>> smallest = [min(zip(l,range(len(l)))) for l in zip(*lists)]
>>> smallest
[(11.401754250991379, 1), (16.278820596099706, 1), (42.059481689626182, 1), (40.792156108742276, 1), (17.691806012954132, 0), (27.018512172212592, 1), (20.808652046684813, 0), (37.443290453698111, 2)]
```

We could have been clever and not brought along the minimum value, but it doesn't really matter.

Since you may have as many centriods, to make it dynamic, don't use *variables*, use a *container*. A list would do, but `dict`s are easy:

```
>>> clusters = {}
>>> for j, (_, i) in enumerate(smallest):
...     clusters.setdefault(i,[]).append(dataPoints[j])
...
```

Finally,

```
>>> pprint(clusters)
{0: [array([16, 32]), array([20, 56])],
 1: [array([2, 4]),
     array([17,  4]),
     array([45,  2]),
     array([45,  7]),
     array([32, 14])],
 2: [array([68, 33])]}
```

Finally, I would stick with *either lists or np.arrays*. Rarely are both appropriate. And you should understand the pros-and-cons of each, so you know which is the appropriate data-structure for your problem. This is a very important aspect of writing code.

Comment: Works like a charm! I've been playing with finding the mean value of each 'cluster', is there a built in function that could help me with that? I'll definitely pay more attention to what data type I am using next time.

Comment: @cparks10 If you have a list of arrays, this is actually quite straightforward: `means = {k: sum(v)/len(v) for k,v in clusters.items()}`.

Comment: @ juanpa.arrivillaga What if I am just wanting it to return the values and not the keys? So instead of the {0: array([18, 44]), 1: array([2, 4]), 2: array([41, 12])} I would just get [[18,44],[2,4],[41,12]] or whatever would be the best format to use to compare the means to by original centroid array/list?

Comment: @ juanpa.arrivillaga I've got the issue rasied in a new question. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42684945/how-i-select-format-only-the-values-from-a-dictionary-into-a-list-or-numpy-array/42685451?noredirect=1#comment72495266_42685451