# How I select/format only the values from a dictionary into a list or numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary

How do I get it to print just a list of the averages?
   I just need it to be the exact same format as my np
   arrays so I can compare them to see if they are the same or not.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from pprint import pprint

centroids = np.array([[3,44],[4,15],[5,15]])
dataPoints = np.array([[2,4],[17,4],[45,2],[45,7],[16,32],[32,14],[20,56],[68,33]])

def size(vector):
    return np.sqrt(sum(x**2 for x in vector))

def distance(vector1, vector2):
    return size(vector1 - vector2)

def distances(array1, array2):
    lists = [[distance(vector1, vector2) for vector2 in array2] for vector1 in array1]
    #print lists.index(min, zip(*lists))
    smallest = [min(zip(l,range(len(l)))) for l in zip(*lists)]
    clusters = {}
    for j, (_, i) in enumerate(smallest):
        clusters.setdefault(i,[]).append(dataPoints[j])
    pprint (clusters)
    print'\nAverage of Each Point'
    avgDict = {}
    for k,v in clusters.iteritems():
        avgDict[k] = sum(v)/ (len(v))
    avgList = np.asarray(avgDict)
    pprint (avgList)

distances(centroids,dataPoints)
```

Current Output:

```
{0: [array([16, 32]), array([20, 56])],
 1: [array([2, 4])],
 2: [array([17,  4]),
     array([45,  2]),
     array([45,  7]),
     array([32, 14]),
     array([68, 33])]}

Average of Each Point
array({0: array([18, 44]), 1: array([2, 4]), 2: array([41, 12])}, dtype=object)
```

Desired Output:

```
[[18,44],[2,4],[41,12]]
```

Or whatever the best format to compare my arrays/lists. I am aware I should have just stuck with one data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you try to cluster the `dataPoints` by the index of the nearest `centroids`, and find out the average position of the clustered points?  If it is, I advise to use some broadcast rules of numpy to get the output you need.

Consider this,

```py
    np.linalg.norm(centroids[None, :, :] - dataPoints[:, None, :], axis=-1)
```

It creates a matrix showing all distances between `dataPoints` and `centroids`,

```py
    array([[ 40.01249805,  11.18033989,  11.40175425],
           [ 42.3792402 ,  17.02938637,  16.2788206 ],
           [ 59.39696962,  43.01162634,  42.05948169],
           [ 55.97320788,  41.77319715,  40.79215611],
           [ 17.69180601,  20.80865205,  20.24845673],
           [ 41.72529209,  28.01785145,  27.01851217],
           [ 20.80865205,  44.01136217,  43.65775991],
           [ 65.9241989 ,  66.48308055,  65.520989  ]])
```

And you can compute the indices of the nearest centroids by this trick (they are split into 3 lines for readability),

```py
    In: t0 = centroids[None, :, :] - dataPoints[:, None, :]
    In: t1 = np.linalg.norm(t0, axis=-1)
    In: t2 = np.argmin(t1, axis=-1)
```

Now `t2` has the indices,

```py
    array([1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2])
```

To find the #1 cluster, use the boolean mask `t2 == 0`,

```py
    In: dataPoints[t2 == 0]
    Out: array([[16, 32],
                [20, 56]])

    In: dataPoints[t2 == 1]
    Out: array([[2, 4]])

    In: dataPoints[t2 == 2]
    Out: array([[17,  4],
                [45,  2],
                [45,  7],
                [32, 14],
                [68, 33]])
```

Or just calculate the average in your case,

```py
    In: np.mean(dataPoints[t2 == 0], axis=0)
    Out: array([ 18.,  44.])

    In: np.mean(dataPoints[t2 == 1], axis=0)
    Out: array([ 2.,  4.])

    In: np.mean(dataPoints[t2 == 2], axis=0)
    Out: array([ 41.4,  12. ])
```

Of course, the latter blocks can be rewritten in for-loop if you want.

It might be a good practice to formulate the solution by numpy's conventions in my opinion.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: The program has been running fine, but more often than not I am getting a 'mean of empty slice' error. Would you mind giving me a bit of help with this? Another user suggested a solution that works, but it does not leave my with the amount of clusters that are asked for. Here is a link to the post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43100855/how-can-i-prevent-nan-issues/43101359?noredirect=1#comment73292238_43101359