# How can I prevent NAN issues?

Tags: python, numpy, k-means

I'm getting `Mean of empty slice` runtime warnings.
When I print out what my variables are (numpy arrays), several
of them contain `nan` values. The Runtime Warning is looking at line 
58 as the issue. What can I change to make it work?

Sometimes the program will run with no issues. Most times it does
not.

This is a K-Means from scratch algorithm that is clustering
the iris data set. It first prompts the users for the amount of 
centroids they want (clusters). It then randomly generates said
number of clusters in the given range from the numbers in the loaded
in text file.

I have the break value in the else statement to prevent infinite 
loops.

Is it because I am having numbers go below zero when I subtract the
Centroids from the data points in the file?

Error I get when I run:

```
How Many Centrouds? 3
Dimensionality of Data:  (150, 4)
Starting Centroiuds:
 [[ 1.4  7.9  0.2  3.4]
 [ 7.8  0.2  4.3  1.4]
 [ 5.7  6.9  3.   6.6]]
t0 :
 [[[-3.7  4.4 -1.2  3.2]
  [ 2.7 -3.3  2.9  1.2]
  [ 0.6  3.4  1.6  6.4]]

 [[-3.5  4.9 -1.2  3.2]
  [ 2.9 -2.8  2.9  1.2]
  [ 0.8  3.9  1.6  6.4]]

 [[-3.3  4.7 -1.1  3.2]
  [ 3.1 -3.   3.   1.2]
  [ 1.   3.7  1.7  6.4]]

 ..., 
 [[-5.1  4.9 -5.   1.4]
  [ 1.3 -2.8 -0.9 -0.6]
  [-0.8  3.9 -2.2  4.6]]

 [[-4.8  4.5 -5.2  1.1]
  [ 1.6 -3.2 -1.1 -0.9]
  [-0.5  3.5 -2.4  4.3]]

 [[-4.5  4.9 -4.9  1.6]
  [ 1.9 -2.8 -0.8 -0.4]
  [-0.2  3.9 -2.1  4.8]]]

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 59
    warnings.warn("Mean of empty slice.", RuntimeWarning)
RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice.

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 68
    ret, rcount, out=ret, casting='unsafe', subok=False)
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
---------------
Starting Centroids:

[[ 1.4  7.9  0.2  3.4]
 [ 7.8  0.2  4.3  1.4]
 [ 5.7  6.9  3.   6.6]]


Starting NewMeans:

[[        nan         nan         nan         nan]
 [ 5.84333333  3.054       3.75866667  1.19866667]
 [        nan         nan         nan         nan]]
Starting Centroids Now:

[[        nan         nan         nan         nan]
 [ 5.84333333  3.054       3.75866667  1.19866667]
 [        nan         nan         nan         nan]]


NewMeans now:
[[        nan         nan         nan         nan]
 [ 5.84333333  3.054       3.75866667  1.19866667]
 [        nan         nan         nan         nan]]
```

Python Code:

```
import numpy as np
from pprint import pprint
import random
import sys
import warnings

arglist = sys.argv 

#UNCOMMENT BELOW IN FINAL PROGRAM
'''
NoOfCentroids = int(arglist[2])
dataPointsFromFile = np.array(np.loadtxt(sys.argv[1], delimiter = ','))
'''

dataPointsFromFile = np.array(np.loadtxt('iris.txt', delimiter = ','))

NoOfCentroids = input('How Many Centrouds? ')

dataRange = ([])

#UNCOMMENT BELOW IN FINAL PROGRAM
'''
with open(arglist[1]) as f:
    print 'Points in data set: ',sum(1 for _ in f)
'''
dataRange.append(round(np.amin(dataPointsFromFile),1))
dataRange.append(round(np.amax(dataPointsFromFile),1))
dataRange = np.asarray(dataRange)

dataPoints = np.array(dataPointsFromFile)
print 'Dimensionality of Data: ', dataPoints.shape

randomCentroids = []
data = ([])
templist = []
i = 0

while i<NoOfCentroids:
    for j in range(len(dataPointsFromFile[1,:])):
        cat = round(random.uniform(np.amin(dataPointsFromFile),np.amax(dataPointsFromFile)),1)
        templist.append(cat)
    randomCentroids.append(templist)
    templist = []
    i = i+1

centroids = np.asarray(randomCentroids)

def kMeans(array1, array2):
    ConvergenceCounter = 1
    keepGoing = True
    StartingCentroids = np.copy(centroids)
    print 'Starting Centroiuds:\n {}'.format(StartingCentroids)
    while keepGoing:      
        #--------------Find The new means---------#
        t0 = StartingCentroids[None, :, :] - dataPoints[:, None, :]
        print 't0 :\n {}'.format(t0)
        t1 = np.linalg.norm(t0, axis=-1)
        t2 = np.argmin(t1, axis=-1)
        #------Push the new means to a new array for comparison---------#
        CentroidMeans = []
        for x in range(len(StartingCentroids)):
            CentroidMeans.append(np.mean(dataPoints[t2 == [x]], axis=0))
        #--------Convert to a numpy array--------#
        NewMeans = np.asarray(CentroidMeans)
        #------Compare the New Means with the Starting Means------#
        if np.array_equal(NewMeans,StartingCentroids):
            print ('Convergence has been reached after {} moves'.format(ConvergenceCounter))
            print ('Starting Centroids:\n{}'.format(centroids))
            print ('Final Means:\n{}'.format(NewMeans))
            print ('Final Cluster assignments: {}'.format(t2))
            for x in xrange(len(StartingCentroids)):
                print ('Cluster {}:\n'.format(x)), dataPoints[t2 == [x]]
            for x in xrange(len(StartingCentroids)):
                print ('Size of Cluster {}:'.format(x)), len(dataPoints[t2 == [x]])
            keepGoing = False
        else:
            print 15*'-'
            ConvergenceCounter  = ConvergenceCounter +1
            print 'Starting Centroids:\n'
            print StartingCentroids
            print '\n'
            print 'Starting NewMeans:\n'
            print NewMeans
            StartingCentroids =np.copy(NewMeans)
            print 'Starting Centroids Now:\n'
            print StartingCentroids
            print '\n'
            print 'NewMeans now:'
            print NewMeans
            break


kMeans(centroids, dataPoints)
```

Comment: In `data = ([])`, the `()` does nothing.  `([],)` would make a 1 element tuple, but I don't think that's what you want.  `data = []` should be sufficient, as you do with `templist`.  Do you even use `data` later in the code?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the warning comes up in

```
np.mean(dataPoints[t2 == [x]], axis=0)
```

If `t2 == [x]` is all False (no match between `t2` and `x`, then `dataPoints[...]` will be an empty array, resulting in the `mean` warning.

I think you need to be more careful with that test.  Maybe even skip the `mean` if the masked array is empty.

`==` tests with floating values are unpredictable.  You need to use something like `np.isclose` or `np.allclose` to test equivalence with a tolerance.

The second warning comes from later in  the `mean` calc, presumably when trying to divide by 0, the number of elements.

The full `mean` code can be found in `numpy.core._methods.py`.

In sum, don't try to take the `mean` of an empty array.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately the when testing the equivalence they need to be exact. Is there a way I could do some exception handling say to check if there is a mean slice error, and if there is re-run the program with different starting centroids until it works?

Comment: If `np.any(t2 == [x])` take the `mean`, otherwise skip it.

Comment: Thanks! That works! The only problem it leaves me with is that I do not end up with the amount of centroids that is asked for at the beginning of the program. How would I fix that?