# Is my function call in an if statement screwing me up?

Tags: python, function, numpy, k-means

I've been working on a homework assignment to implement a K-Means clustering 
algorithm from scratch. I am clustering the Iris Flower dataset. 
At the beginning of the program, the user is prompted for the amount of 
centroids (clusters) they would like. The program then creates a range to 
chose from to create the centroids based of the data in the file.

I was having issues with a 'mean of empty slice' error, so I decided to 
try and control all of this with another while loop and conditional statements. 
Basically preventing me from getting errors. It checks to see if all of the 
Centroids are good, and if they are not, generate new ones. But I see to be losing centroids in the process. What is happening?

Python Code:

```
import numpy as np
from pprint import pprint
import random
import sys

dataPointsFromFile = np.array(np.loadtxt('iris.txt', delimiter = ','))

NoOfCentroids = input('How Many Centrouds? ')
```

Create the Range for the centroids to be in

```
dataRange = ([])
dataRange.append(round(np.amin(dataPointsFromFile),1))
dataRange.append(round(np.amax(dataPointsFromFile),1))
dataRange = np.asarray(dataRange)

dataPoints = np.array(dataPointsFromFile)

centroids = 0
```

Function To make the centroids

```
def CentroidMaker(number):
    global centroids
    centroids = 0
    i=0
    randomCentroids = []
    templist = []
    while i<NoOfCentroids:
        for j in range(len(dataPointsFromFile[1,:])):
            cat = round(random.uniform(np.amin(dataPointsFromFile),np.amax(dataPointsFromFile)),1)
            templist.append(cat)
        randomCentroids.append(templist)
        templist = []
        i = i+1
    centroids = np.asarray(randomCentroids)
    return centroids
```

K-Means function to run the clustering Algorithm
    def kMeans(data):
        print 'In K Means Function'

```
    ConvergenceCounter = 1
    keepGoing = True
    StillKeepGoing = True

#Check to make sure centroids were passed into the function
    print NoOfCentroids
    CentroidMaker(NoOfCentroids)
    print centroids

    StartingCentroids = np.copy(centroids)
    #print 'Starting Centroiuds:\n {}'.format(StartingCentroids)
    while keepGoing:


 #Where I think the problem resides  


        while StillKeepGoing:
            StartingCentroids = np.copy(centroids)
            #--------------Find The new means---------#
            t0 = StartingCentroids[None, :, :] - dataPoints[:, None, :]
            t1 = np.linalg.norm(t0, axis=-1)
            t2 = np.argmin(t1, axis=-1)
            #------Push the new means to a new array for comparison---------#
            CentroidMeans = []
            for x in range(len(StartingCentroids)):
                #if they are all true, get outta the loop!
                if np.all(t2==[x]):
                    CentroidMeans.append(np.mean(dataPoints[t2 == [x]], axis=0))
                    StillKeepGoing = False
                #If they are all not true, generate new ones!
            if np.any(t2!=[x]):
                CentroidMaker(NoOfCentroids)


        #--------Convert to a numpy array--------#
        NewMeans = np.asarray(CentroidMeans)
        #------Compare the New Means with the Starting Means------#
        if np.array_equal(NewMeans,StartingCentroids):
            print ('Convergence has been reached after {} moves'.format(ConvergenceCounter))
            print ('Starting Centroids:\n{}'.format(centroids))
            print ('Final Means:\n{}'.format(NewMeans))
            print ('Final Cluster assignments: {}'.format(t2))
            for x in xrange(len(StartingCentroids)):
                print ('Cluster {}:\n'.format(x)), dataPoints[t2 == [x]]
            for x in xrange(len(StartingCentroids)):
                print ('Size of Cluster {}:'.format(x)), len(dataPoints[t2 == [x]])
            keepGoing = False
        else:
            ConvergenceCounter  = ConvergenceCounter +1
            StartingCentroids =np.copy(NewMeans)

kMeans(dataPoints)
```

Comment: @Voo Sorry :( It's just a description of the problem, my python code, the current incorrect output, and a desired correct output. I can reformat it any way you would like. I'm really sorry, I was just trying to give a clear example.

Comment: What you should shoot for is a [Minimal, Complete, And Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not only will that make it more likely that people take the time to look at it, at the same time creating such an example very often helps you find your own problem.

Comment: This is a sequel to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43100855/how-can-i-prevent-nan-issues, which had problems when the `np.mean` got an empty array.  This now runs without error or warning, but the values are wrong.  That's a harder problem to reduce to a minimal case, and harder to diagnose and help.

Comment: @Voo I edited the question. Got rid of the outputs and broke the code down a bit more.

Comment: @hpaulj But in my code above I am trying to make sure that there is no empty array slice. I took your advice and if all of the points do not return true, then I am trying to generate new random centroids and pass those. If they all return true, then run the code. I think that is where the problem is. The problem I had with how we were doing it yesterday was that it did not return the original amount of clusters that I was asking for, which is the whole point of the program.